# Поиск по условию

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив объектов цен. У каждого объекта цены есть её значение и условие применения, которое зависит от количество заказанных продуктов для этой цены.

Допустим, в корзине лежит товар Pan в количестве 125 штук по цене 2 за штуку. Я пытаюсь получить и вывести следующую возможную цену на этот товар (если смотреть ниже, то это 1 за штуку, если заказано более 500 штук товара).

```js
// В корзине лежит товар Pan в количестве 125 штук по цене 2 за штуку.
let cart = [{
  id: 5854,
  name: 'Pan',
  quantity: 125,
  price: 2,
  attributes: {
    // Все возможные цены на товар Pan в зависимости от заказанного количества
    prices: [{
        id: 1,
        value: 10,
        condition_quantity: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: 8,
        condition_quantity: 5,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        value: 6,
        condition_quantity: 10,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        value: 4,
        condition_quantity: 50,
      },
      {
        id: 777,
        value: 1,
        condition_quantity: 500,
      },
      {
        id: 900,
        value: 2,
        condition_quantity: 100,
      },
    ]
  },
}];

function conditionPrice(item) {
  //все цены, кроме текущей
  let prices = item.attributes.prices.filter(row => row.value != item.price);

  //перебираем и сохраняем только те, которые имеют условие для применения цены
  let prices_for_select = [];
  for (let key in prices) {
    let price = prices[key];
    if (price.condition_quantity > 0) {
      prices_for_select.push(price);
    }
  }

  //определяем, какая цена подходит
  if (prices_for_select.length > 0) {
    let min = prices_for_select[0];
    for (let key in prices_for_select) {
      let price = prices_for_select[key];
      if (price.condition_quantity < min.condition_quantity && price.condition_quantity > item.quantity) {
        min = price;
      }
    }
    return min;
  }

  return false;
}


console.log(conditionPrice(cart[0]));
```

Но что-то работает не так...

Ожидаемый выход

Пример 1

- Заказано товаров 125.
- Следующая цена - 1 от 500 штук

Пример 2

- Заказано товаров 505.
- Следующая цена - нет

Пример 3

- Заказано товаров 2.
- Следующая цена - 8 от 5 штук

Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное так подойдет:

```
function conditionPrice(item) {
  return item.attributes.prices
             // отфильтруем все что меньше
             .filter(i => i.condition_quantity >= item.quantity) 
             // отсортируем по увеличению значения condition_quantity
             .sort((a,b) => a.condition_quantity - b.condition_quantity)
             // вернем первый элемент
             .shift(); 
}
```

```js
// В корзине лежит товар Pan в количестве 125 штук по цене 2 за штуку.
let cart = [{
  id: 5854,
  name: 'Pan',
  quantity: 125,
  price: 2,
  attributes: {
    // Все возможные цены на товар Pan в зависимости от заказанного количества
    prices: [{
        id: 1,
        value: 10,
        condition_quantity: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: 8,
        condition_quantity: 5,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        value: 6,
        condition_quantity: 10,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        value: 4,
        condition_quantity: 50,
      },
      {
        id: 777,
        value: 1,
        condition_quantity: 500,
      },
      {
        id: 900,
        value: 2,
        condition_quantity: 100,
      },
    ]
  },
}];

function conditionPrice(item) {
  return item.attributes.prices
             .filter(i => i.condition_quantity >= item.quantity)
             .sort((a,b) => a.condition_quantity - b.condition_quantity)
             .shift();
}


console.log(conditionPrice(cart[0]));
```